# WCF Data services or something else?

Tags: wcf, service

For a WPF client and Sql Server database application, I plan to use WCF data services for passing data between client and the database but I find the WCF client too limited in its abilities. Complex LINQ queries with JOINS etc. cannot be sent over to the server.

Is there another techonology that I should use here which supports complex LINQ queries from client to the server?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specified in what kind of "complex" LINQ queries you have that WCF Data Services doesn't support??

Comment: Hi Marc_s, I tried running a linq query from client that contained a JOIN operator but it did ot work and later found out JOIN is not supported in linq queries from client possibly because it cannot be converted into a valid http uri. so that made me wonder if wcf data services is mature enough for enterprise level apps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely correct that you can't join data using OData (a.k.a. WCF Data Services). It's just that LINQ to OData does not support join syntax. However you can still retrive results from intersection of multiple tables using either Expand method or simply by specifying a relationship in a select clause. For example, if you have a table User with relationship to Phone table, you can write "from u in ctx.User.Expand("Phone")...", or you can write "from u in ctx.User select new { u.Name, u.Phone }", and it will retrive Phone collection.

I am not aware of any other RESTful LINQ provider that would support querying SQL data.

Comment: Thanks Vagif. I will try the solution you've suggested.

Comment: Thanks Vagif. In my case the User is not directly associated with Phone in the entity model. In my case Phone might be linked to User, Customer or vendor basically any parent So I have not associated the Phone table with these "Parent" tables in the database. The only way to associate these in my queries is using entity SQL JOINs. The soution you have suggested won't work for my case. May be I should try some other approach.